# Conditions about the fields in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a User Class which has_many sessions.
I would like to write a query that count the number of sessions each user have, **in a specific time range**.

In other words, I'm looks for a query that looks something like that:
User.where(:sessions.date => date1..date2)

What is the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use simple `$gt` and `$lt` for this as it allows to query just for one of them, but of course there is also a `$in` operator.

```
# Session seems to be a separate collection
sessions = Session.where(:date => {"$gt" => date1, "$lt" => date2})
User.find(sessions.collect(&:user_id).uniq)
```

Aside this, your query looks a perfect candidate for an aggregation pipeline to transfer less data from the db in the `Session` query.